# shp to topojson conversion : no output

Tags: dictionary, gis, cartography, topojson

Topojson's doc [states](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#input-and-output):

*You can specify ESRI shapefiles as input:*

```
topojson -o output.json input.shp
```

My `.shp` file is valid, `npm` and `topojson` are installed, and I'am in the input file's directory (`cd`). This `topojson` command simply doesn't work on my side, no output, nor feedback produced.

**How do you convert `shp` into `topojson` on your side ?**

---

`which topojson` gives `/usr/local/bin/topojson`

`which ogr2ogr` gives `/usr/bin/ogr2ogr`

On ubuntu 13.04, but I think my issue is not related to ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodesjs was corrupted, I had to remove, clean up, then reinstall nodejs & topojson. See [this overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17325367/1974961)