# How to know if topojson is installed and working normally?

Tags: d3.js, gis, geojson, shapefile, topojson

**How to know if topojson is well installed and working normally?**

An example tiny file to convert will be appreciate. with both the source and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had a corrupted version of nodejs. I first cleaned up my mess:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm topojson
```

Then the following consoles allowed a clean reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
--
sudo npm install -g topojson
```

Then my file merging worked fine :

```
cd /myfolder/
topojson -o output.json input1.json input2.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't stumbled across this yet I found it to be a great walkthrough of the entire process: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

The above link also includes the command to run to check if topojson is installed:

```
$which topojson
```

If topojson is installed correctly this will print out the directory where it's installed, which might look something like this (but could be different):

```
/usr/local/bin/topojson
```

If the command doesn't print anything then you'll have to double check your install.

If you visit the link I posted you can also find example shapefiles under the heading #Finding Data.

Good luck!

Comment: **Edit:**

    $Which topojson
    > /usr/local/bin/topojson

This is a single link toward `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson`, a valid JS script. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson` is the folder which really contain all topojson folders and files. However, my command `topojson -o output.json input.shp` and others still doesn't print/output anything.