# toposon is not installing

Tags: topojson

To install toposon I am running

```
run npm install -g topojson
```

in command prompt

It throws error `'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I have also install GDAL

Please help me in installing toposon on windows 7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just `npm install -g topojson`?

Comment: yes it gives error 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install node.js?

Comment: yes installed node.js

Comment: Try out that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17325367/1974961

Comment: But he needs it for Windows @Hugolpz, so try it with tutorial of mine in German: http://www.kwoxer.de/2015/01/26/topojson-contextify-node-gym-unter-windows-installieren-tutorial/