# npm install <module> persistent error ? (node-gyp build ?)

Tags: node.js, npm, jsdom, node-gyp, contextify

I try to install jsdom such:

```
$ sudo npm install -g jsdom
# OR
$ sudo npm install    jsdom
```

After some successfull command, the install quickly fails, with the first error message being after the `[....]` :

```
$ sudo npm install jsdom 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
[....]

> contextify@0.1.7 install /home/yug/Desktop/QGis/WikiAtlas/1_shaded_relief/test/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp: /home/yug/.node-gyp/0.10.25/common.gypi not found (cwd: /home/yug/Desktop/QGis/WikiAtlas/1_shaded_relief/test/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify) while reading includes of binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/yug/Desktop/QGis/WikiAtlas/1_shaded_relief/test/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "jsdom"
npm ERR! cwd /home/yug/Desktop/QGis/WikiAtlas/1_shaded_relief/test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/entities
....
```

Hint? This bug also appears for other modules :

```
 $sudo npm install -g topojson 
 #bug with `contextify@0.1.7 install` error as well.
```

[image]

**How to fix that ?**

---

**Edit:** I tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm topojson` then reinstalling via various ways. **Even when `nodejs` reinstall is successfull, the error stays**, so I guess it's rather contextual (`node.gyp` ? `cwd` ? ...). Remove/reinstall ways tried :

- [ubuntu_setup.sh](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs)

  - with native outdated url
  - with url updated to https://github.com/joyent/node.git,
- [`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17325367/1974961),
- and handmade `git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git` (trial canceled)
- using [various other ways](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) :

  - way1 : ogoing

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue? I have the same

Comment: Nope. Vote up this question may increase a bit its visibility.

Comment: Interestingly, I now seems to have the same bug with `npm install -g topojson`.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling nodejs?  BTW i tried on windows I get ENOENT.

Comment: Reinstall don't seems to work, it's [likely] something else, maybe `node-gyp`. I have difficulties to make sense of the error message Edit: See question, I added the reinstall trials O made.

Comment: do you have python installed?

Comment: yes : 

which python python2.7-config python3.3 python-config python2 python2-config python3.3m python2.7 python3 python3m
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python3.3
/usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2-config
/usr/bin/python3.3m
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3m

Comment: I'am exploring the possibility of packages confusion since [`node` is not `nodejs`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22476593/1974961), but I already checked that 3 months earlier, and was not that.

Comment: @MrMins: Seems I found a way, you can try out or share your solution. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I found a way by carefully deleting all node-related file and folder on my computer.

**0. Context:** I previously made several unsuccessful console clean-ups, with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm topojson
```

followed by ~3 different ways to reinstall `nodejs`. I tried EACH way, from clean-up to reinstall, between 2 & 4 times.

**1. Terminal purging:** Let's first cleaned up my mess the deepest way possible:

```
npm cache clean; bower cache clean; grunt clean;
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm topojson
```

Yet, I just noticed that **this deep purge does NOT purge/delete installed node modules**, which stay persistent.

**2. Hand purge:** Also, I pushed the purge further with an hand purge for both `nodejs` and `node_modules`. I looked for **ALL** related folders on my computer, nearer the root (ubuntu: `/home/<user>/`) the better. I was careful to delete all previously installed global `.../node-modules/` folders, without deleting local modules (specific local installations, which were still working).

**3. Reinstall:** Then the following consoles allowed a clean reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo npm install -g topojson jsdom
```

Afterwhat, my file conversion via npm module `topojson` (depending itself on `jsdom`) worked fine :

```
cd /myfolder/
topojson -o output.topo.json input.geo.json
```

**4. Conclusion:** I can not identify why, which file/folder deletion allowed the successful `sudo apt-get install nodejs` + `sudo npm install -g topojson` reinstall. But thist deep cleanup via mouse and recursive remove `sudo rm -r [node related folder/file]` definitively unlocked my situation.

/!\ Be **very careful** with the **`rm -r` recursive remove**. /!\

Comment: Yeah, works, thanks for share the answer. I just have a new problem after change the version of python (from python 2.5 to 2.7), but was solved installing the `open-jdk`.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I too was having consistent issues with installation and for me it was the default version of node that I was on (0.11.13-beta). I installed 'n' (https://github.com/visionmedia/n) and switched to version 0.10.26 (which was working fine on another machine) and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 10):

As you're finding out from the comments, this is a very common issue. So common, in fact, that the authors of jsdom have documented it right in the README file for the project's git repository.

---

#### TL;DR

You need to have a C++ compiler and Python2.7 installed on your machine to install **contextify** which is a dependency of **jsdom**. Otherwise, the jsdom install will fail.

---

From the README on the [Github page for jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom):

> ## Contextify
>
> Contextify is a dependency of jsdom, used for running `<script>` tags within the page. In other words, it allows jsdom, which is run in Node.js, to run strings of JavaScript in an isolated environment that pretends to be a browser environment instead of a server. You can see how this is an important feature.
>
> Unfortunately, doing this kind of magic requires C++. And in Node.js, using C++ from JavaScript means using "native modules." Native modules are compiled at installation time so that they work precisely for your machine; that is, you don't download a contextify binary from npm, but instead build one locally after downloading the source from npm.
>
> Unfortunately, getting C++ compiled within npm's installation system can be tricky, especially for Windows users. Thus, one of the most common problems with jsdom is trying to use it without the proper compilation tools installed. Here's what you need to compile Contextify, and thus to install jsdom:
>
> ### Windows
>
> - A recent copy of the x86 version of Node.js for Windows, not the x64 version.
> - A copy of Visual C++ 2010 Express.
> - A copy of Python 2.7, installed in the default location of C:\Python27.
>
> There are some slight modifications to this that can work; for example full versions of Visual Studio usually work, and sometimes you can even get an x64 version of Node.js working too. But it's tricky, so start with the basics!
>
> ### Mac
>
> - XCode needs to be installed
> - "Command line tools for XCode" need to be installed
> - Launch XCode once to accept the license, etc. and ensure it's properly installed
>
> ### Linux
>
> You'll need various build tools installed, like make, Python 2.7, and a compiler toolchain. How to install these will be specific to your distro, if you don't already have them.

Try installing **jsdom** again after satisfying the requirements mentioned above for your OS, and see if that solves it.

By the way, you are getting the same issue with **topojson** because it has a dependency on **d3** which in turn depends on **jsdom**, so it is just the same problem installing jsdom. Hope this helps!

**--EDIT--**

Since it sounds like you're using Ubuntu, I would recommend starting with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This will install **make** and **g++** and some other tools. This package and Python2.7 is probably about all you'll need to successfully install contextify.

Comment: Seems I do have these dependencies. Still unsolve. To others: if this answer fix your issue, please upvote and notice us~

Comment: Seems I found a way by carefully deleting all node-related file on my computer. See my answer nearby.

Comment: Thanks for the help tho, It pushed me toward more tests. The bounty is yours : )

Comment: Under Windows I got it working with the 32 bit versions of node.js and Python 2.7.6 and Visual C++ 2010 Express only after setting the PYTHON  environment variable to C:\Python27\python.exe not C:\Python27 as mentioned here https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4047#issuecomment-8876536

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1b:** I [suspect][1] the `rm -r /home/<user>/local/lib/node_modules/` to be the key element unlocking the situation. You may list the global (`-g`) node_modules, then remove the relevant one(s) (`topojson` and/or `jsdom` and/or `node-gyp`) specifically, then reinstall it(them).

**Commands:** On ubuntu, try...

```
 cd /home/<user>/local/lib/node_modules/  #replace <user> by relevant user name to set your cwd
 ls -1      # give the list of global modules names
 rm -r /<module_name>    #replace <module_name> by relevant name to remove it
 sudo npm install -g <module_name>  #replace <module_name> by relevant name for global install
```

Note: `topojson` depends on `jsdom` and `npm-gyp`.

[1]: not tried, but makes sense according to my diagnostic.