# topojson-svg : how to make it works?

Tags: geojson, topojson

**Tweet:** Mike Bostock [recently tweeted](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/461540145322156035):

> If you like making maps in Illustrator, **TopoJSON 1.6.9** supports conversion to SVG. No code
>   required! https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/bin/topojson-svg 
>   ——Mike Bostock (@mbostock) 30 Avril 2014

Cool !

**Topojson version:** on my terminal, I checked the version...

```
$topojson --version
>1.6.11
$node --version
>v0.10.25
```

Seems good.

**Topojson-svg trial:** so I gave it a shoot...

```
curl -o uk.topo.json 'http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/uk.json' #get an online topoJSON file
topojson-svg -o output.svg uk.topo.json    #this fails
```

**Error:** I get a corrupt .svg file together with this ugly error message

```
fs.js:393
  binding.close(fd, makeCallback(callback));
          ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at Object.fs.close (fs.js:393:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yug/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson-svg:85:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

**Question: How to process to successfully use `topojson-svg` ?**

---

**Edit:** also occured with recently installed local (non-global) `/node_module` :

```
npm install topojson       #locally install topojson.js & topojson-svg
curl -o uk.topo.json 'http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/uk.json' #get an online topoJSON file
node_modules/.bin/topojson-svg -o output.svg uk.topo.json    #this fails
```

Comment: Old version of node.js? Probably a better question for the mailing list given that this is a very recent thing.

Comment: `$node --version` => `v0.10.25`. Well tried! I slapped my `nodejs` with a [deep purge and reinstall from scratch just yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23474114/1974961). :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Were you successful with topojson-svg, if so, which are your `node --version` ? which exact topojson-svg command did you used ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: **[Fixed on github within 4minutes after reporting the issue](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/172).** #OMG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Fixed on github within 4minutes after reporting the issue](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/172).**

Will be available within hours/days on `npm`, with [topojson v.1.6.12+](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/commit/053f1801627465595053c89f2d9d04c3d6242db8)